Does Enabling general_log in Aurora MySQL Show SSL Encryption Status of Connections?
I'm looking to determine if connections to my Aurora MySQL instance are SSL encrypted. Specifically, I want to know if enabling the general_log in the parameter group will provide information about the encryption status of each connection.
Ideally, the log would include entries similar to this fictional example:
2024-08-07T08:15:00.000000Z    42 Connect    user@hostname on database_name using SSL/TLS

where it clearly indicates whether a specific connection is using SSL or not.
I am aware of the mysql> status command, which outputs:
mysql> status
--------------
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.30, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1

Connection id:      12
Current database:
Current user:       replicator@domU-12-31-39-10-54-BD.compute-1.internal
SSL:            Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA

However, this only reflects the current manual connection and does not provide insight into connections made by applications.
Is there a way to determine the SSL status of each connection automatically? Are there any other options or best practices for monitoring the SSL encryption status of connections to Aurora MySQL?
Thanks in advance!

By default Aurora databases enforce SSL/TLS in it's endpoints, you can check that on DB cluster / instance parameter group in the console, check for parameter :
require_secure_transport

by default it's ON from  : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Reference.ParameterGroups.html
You can also check information about CA and certificate used in Connectivity & security pan in AWS RDS console.
For logging connections you need to enable server_audit_events and export this logs to cloudWatch with needed permissions for Aurora to send logs.
From : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Auditing.html#AuroraMySQL.Auditing.Enable.server_audit_events
Hope this help.
